# Should there be categories related to instruction?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was wondering if there should be some categories related to instruction. I'm going to be asking more and more questions (like [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22275/8490)) related to instructing aviation knowledge and related to instructor activities. In many cases they'll apply to another category. Just brainstorming here.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to lean toward "no" because I fear it would be abused by folks asking *for* instruction (or *about* off-topic things related to instruction, like "Which flight school should I pick?" rather than "How should I go about selecting a flight school?")

Along the same lines I would probably phrase questions/answers like that one a little differently ("What equipment is required for (type of flight)?" => "You need xxxxx per FAR yyyyy. A convenient mnemonic to remember this is zzzzz"), but that's just a matter of personal preference so they fit into the neat little tagging buckets we already have :)

Comment: Good call. I'm with you.